# Relacionar dos o más datos en una tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Qué tal comunidad. Me crucé con un inconveniente al intentar relacionar dos o más datos entre dos tablas diferentes en mi base de datos.

El escenario que tengo actualmente es el siguiente: Tengo una tabla de cursos y una de alumnos, cuando creé la relación entre ambas (a través de la herramienta de diagramación de phpMyAdmin) me di cuenta que **solo puedo relacionar un curso por alumno**.

Entonces mi pregunta es: **¿es posible relacionar dos o más datos en mi tabla de alumnos?** Un ejemplo básico sería que un alumno pueda inscribirse en **dos (o más)** cursos al mismo tiempo y que esos datos estén sincronizados mutuamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Un alumno puede inscribirse en N cursos (siendo N un entero >= 0), y un curso puede tenerr N alumnos; por lo que se trata de una relación de N a N, para modelarla vas a necesitar una tabla adicional (ej: alumnos_cursos) que tenga al menos dos columnas (id_alumno, id_curso).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que estas intentando hacer es una relación de n:n (muchos a muchos), y tu relación actual es de 1:n (1 a muchos):

**1 a n:**

En este caso 1 alumno puede tener inscrito 1 curso, y un curso lo puede tener inscrito n (muchos) alumnos.

**alumno**

```
| id | nombre   | curso_id |
| -- | -------- | -------- |
| 1  | alumno 1 | 1        |
| 2  | alumno 2 | 1        |
```

**curso**

```
| id | nombre   |
| -- | -------- |
| 1  | curso 1  |
```

Como están creadas estas tablas un alumno no podría tener más de 1 curso ya que la relación es 1 a n (muchos).

**n a n:**

En este caso 1 alumno puede tener inscrito n (muchos) cursos, y 1 curso lo puede tener inscrito n (muchos) alumnos.

**alumno**

```
| id | nombre   |
| -- | -------- |
| 1  | alumno 1 |
| 2  | alumno 2 |
```

**alumno_curso**

```
| id | alumno_id| curso_id |
| -- | -------- | -------- |
| 1  | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | 1        | 2        |
| 3  | 2        | 1        |
| 4  | 2        | 2        |
```

**curso**

```
| id | nombre   |
| -- | -------- |
| 1  | curso 1  |
| 2  | curso 2  |
```

Cada vez que se genere una relación n a n surgirá una tabla nueva que se encarga de almacenar las relaciones entre las 2 tablas.

Comment: Excelente, era lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y explicación.

Answer (score 0):

en si lo que entendi, lo que tu quieres hacer es:
1 tabla con datos de alumnos y 1 tabla con datos de cursos, y relacionarlos entre si, ademas verificar si el alumno esta anotado en dos o mas cursos.
Mi logica seria:
En mi tabla curso crearia un id.
En mi tabla alumno crearia un id_curso_anotado que indicaria a que curso esta anotado
Luego hacer una consulta sql con INNER JOIN asi.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM alumno E JOIN curso D ON E.id_curso_anotado = D.id";
$re = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($re)){
    echo $row['nombre'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['curso'];
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

El $row es un array asociado con ambas tablas, pero ordenadas por el id.
En todo caso si no entendiste muy bien (yo soy algo nuevo con estos temas, pero se me presento el mismo caso) podes buscar mas sobre INNER JOIN que hay mas formas de utilizarlo correctamente.